# Extract values from an array in json in one line in Linux bash with jq

Tags: json, bash, dictionary, jq

I am extending here my [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75214867/extract-values-from-an-array-in-json-in-one-line-in-linux-bash-with-jq) about jq since my requirements changed and I am still confused with map function.

Given such a service-def-test.json (very simplified from my real use case):

```
{
    "definition": {
        "services": [{
                "image": {
                    "name": "img1",
                    "tag": "2.0.1"
                }
            }, {
                "image": {
                    "name": "img2",
                    "tag": "1.4.0"
                }
            }, {
                "image": {
                    "name": "img3",
                    "tag": "1.2.5"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I now would like to get a one-line list of values:

[img1:2.0.1, img2:1.4.0, img3:1.2. 
to store eventually in a COMPONENT_IMAGES variable.

From the previous answer,

```
jq -r '.definition.services | " "COMPONENT_IMAGES=\"\(map(.image.name, .image.tag) | join(", "))\"" ' service-def-test.json
```

generates

```
COMPONENT_IMAGES="img1, 2.0.1, img2, 1.4.0, img3, 1.2.5"
```

but this I want only 3 items in my output array.

I am looking to get

```
COMPONENT_IMAGES="img1:2.0.1, img2:1.4.0, img3:1.2.5"
```

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: I don't use jq, but ... would replacing ... map(.image.name, .image.tag) ... with ... map(.image.name:.image.tag) ... be accepted by syntax and give you what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` lets you filter each array item individually. Here, we descend to `.image`, and concatenate the value of `.name`, a literal colon `":"`, and the value of `.tag`. The mapped array can then be `join`ed with a glue string `", "`.

```bash
jq -r '
  .definition.services
  | "COMPONENT_IMAGES=\"" + (map(.image | .name + ":" + .tag) | join(", ")) + "\""
'
```

```
COMPONENT_IMAGES="img1:2.0.1, img2:1.4.0, img3:1.2.5"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vOZdn6kc1MV)

---

If you prefer using [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C%28foo%29), here's its equivalent:

```bash
jq -r '
  .definition.services
  | "COMPONENT_IMAGES=\"\(map(.image | "\(.name):\(.tag)") | join(", "))\""
'
```

```
COMPONENT_IMAGES="img1:2.0.1, img2:1.4.0, img3:1.2.5"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AM_1kZ-d2vY)

Comment: Suggestion, you could get rid of adding the literal quotes by just converting the string to json. Functionally the same. `"COMPONENT_IMAGES=\(map(...)|...|tojson)"`

Comment: @JeffMercado Good idea! `@sh` would be another option in view of the purpose of the construction ("to store eventually in a COMPONENT_IMAGES variable").

Comment: eventually, I need only a space (without ',') as separator, and don't need the "" around so I am using this: "COMPONENTS="+ (map(.image | .name + ":" + .tag) | join(" "))'

Comment: fyi, the whole is set in a Gitlab job, and the output from jq is set in a env file ( > extract.env )  and then as artifacts:  reports:    dotenv: extract.env